# Printing a list where values are in a specific distance from each other using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list,

```
A = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
```

if user input `x = 4`, then I need an output that shows every value that is 4 distance away from each other.
If starting from 'A' after printing values that are 4 distance away from each other ie:  {'A', 'E'}, the code should iterate back and start from 'B' to print all values from there ie: {'B', 'F'}

No number can be in more than one group

Any help is going to be appreciated since I am very new to python.

this is what I have done

```
x = input("enter the number to divide with: ")
A = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']

print("Team A is divided by " +x+ " groups")
print("---------------------")

out = [A[i] for i in range(0, len(A), int(x))]
print(out)
```

My code is printing only the following when user input x =4

```
{'A', 'E'}
```

But I need it to look like the following

```
{'A', 'E'}
{'B', 'F'}
{'C', 'G'}
{'D', 'H'}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip`:

```
out = list(zip(A, A[x:]))
```

For example:

```
x = 4 # int(input("enter the number to divide with: "))
A = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']

print(f"Team A is divided by {x} groups")
print("---------------------")

out = list(zip(A, A[x:]))
print(out)
```

Outputs:

```
[('A', 'E'), ('B', 'F'), ('C', 'G'), ('D', 'H')]
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/UnusualGoodnaturedCookie)

If you want to keep the comprehension:

```
out = [(A[i], A[i+x]) for i in range(0, len(A)-x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can find my answer below.

```
def goutham(alist):
    for passchar in range(0,len(alist)-4):
        i = alist[passchar]
        j = alist[passchar+4]
        print("{"+i+","+j+"}")
        j = 0
 alist = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'] 
 goutham(alist)
```